# Confused in capturing groups and using them further

Tags: regex

I was watching lecture about [regular expressions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkluES9Rvak&t=757s) and at the time [14:52](https://youtu.be/EkluES9Rvak?t=892) she gave to write regex to match the hex codes such as

> #abc
>
> #f00
>
> #BADA55
>
> #C0FFEE

So basically the syntax is -:

1. Start with # sign
2. The following letter can be range [a-fA-F0-9].
3. These letters should be exactly of either of size 3 or 6.

I understood the answer

> /^#([A-Fa-f\d]{3}){1,2}$/g

But what is wrong in mine regex using group capturing -:

> /^#(([A-Fa-f\d]){3}|\2{6})$/

or

> /^#(([A-Fa-f\d]{3})|\2{2})$/

But

> /^#(([A-Fa-f\d]{3})|[A-Fa-f\d]{6})$/

is working

I am using [this](http://leaverou.github.io/regexplained/) for testing my regex.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using alternation; you can't reference a variable in one branch that you capture in another. A bit more in-depth, on your first failing example:

```
/^#(([A-Fa-f\d]){3}|\2{6})$/
```

There are two conceptual errors here.

1. `[A-Fa-f\d]` is **any**  hex digit;

   1. `([A-Fa-f\d])` will capture **a**  hex digit;
   2. `([A-Fa-f\d]){3}` is three hex digits, **one of which**  will be captured (typically the last one).
   3. If you later use `\2`, it will be that one captured digit, not the regexp code for "any hex digit".
2. A deeper problem is this: in order for the digit to be captured, the left side of the alternation will have to succeed. The point of the alternation is that you evaluate either left side or the right one; if the left one succeeds, the right side is not checked! On the other hand, if you fail to match the left side, the right side will also fail, because `\2` is undefined!

EDIT: Also note that `#COFFEE` is not valid, but `#C0FFEE` is.

Comment: I understood the second part of your answer "A deeper problem is ...." but I am unable to fully understand the first part -: " There are two conceptual ....". Please can you explain it here and if possible kindly give me some reference from which I can get much clearer view. Thanx a lot.

Comment: Say we don't have the alternation problem: `/^#(([A-Fa-f\d]){3})\2{3}$/` will match `#abcccc`, but will not match `#abcbbb`, and will definitely not match `#abcdef`. This is because `\2` is not "a hex digit", but specifically `c` (the last of the three matched repetitions of `([A-Fa-f\d])`). Thus `\2{3}` can only ever match `ccc`, if the third character was also `c`.

Comment: that means the /2 will take the value of the () group that came last?

Comment: `\2` will take the last matched value of the second capture group.